# Tagging of modern news articles in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, tagging, sharepoint-news, news-webpart

I have a similar question which has been asked a few times but with a different twist so hoping the brains trust may know of a way of achieving this goal

So essentially I am developing some new modern hub sites that will form an intranet redesign. The concept is areas of the business will have their own portal (hub) which will feed into the main parent hub which is being used to display information across the organisation via targeted/highlighted content and filters etc. Easy enough

What I would like to do is somehow "tag" the news content on the child hubs that feed into the main hub and that information is somehow displayed on the news web part.

I have also tried to make use of adding the sites as a organisation news site as I want to try and get this visual look on the news articles on the main hub, but that concept didn't exactly fit the criteria (it tagged the news articles on the child hubs, but did not tag them on the news web part on the parent hub using the carousel)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-news-site

Appreciate any advice, guidance or feedback!

Thank you